# WinError193 %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, operating-system, artificial-intelligence

For an AI project, I have to use tensorflow with anaconda and spyder. However, I have problem launching Anaconda with a pc and that since last year. I haven't managed to correct that bug because I haven't got to use Anaconda, but now I have to.

I first create an environment with `conda create -n tf2gpu tensorflow-gpu jupyter matplotlib pillow spyder` in the anaconda prompt, then I activate that environment with `conda activate tf2-gpu` and I open spyder via the terminal with `spyder`. (Note : I have a suitable GPU).

Here is the code I am trying to run :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist #datasets
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Activation
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


(tr_imgs,tr_labs),(tst_imgs,tst_labs)=mnist.load_data()
#loading data

print("Training references :",tr_imgs.shape,tr_labs.shape,tr_imgs.dtype,tr_labs.dtype)
#60,000 images of 28 by 28 size with 60,000 labels, both integer 8 bits signed

print("Testing references :",tst_imgs.shape,tst_labs.shape,tst_imgs.dtype,tst_labs.dtype)
#10,000 images of 28 by 28 size with 10,000 labels, both integer 8 bits signed

print("__________________\n")


tr_vec=np.reshape(tr_imgs,(len(tr_imgs),-1)).astype("float32")/255.0
tst_vec=np.reshape(tst_imgs,(len(tst_imgs),-1)).astype("float32")/255.0


cat_trlabs=to_categorical(tr_labs)
cat_tstlabs=to_categorical(tst_labs)


model=Sequential([Dense(251,input_shape=(784,)),Activation("sigmoid"),Dense(128),Activation("sigmoid"),Dense(10),Activation("sigmoid")])

sgd=SGD(learning_rate=0.15,momentum=0.9,decay=0.0,nesterov=False)

model.compile(loss="mse",optimizer=sgd,metrics=["accuracy"])

history=model.fit(tr_vec,cat_trlabs,epochs=100,batch_size=200,validation_split=0.1,verbose=2)

model_history=history.history

prediction=model.predict(tst_vec)

model_loss=model_history["loss"]
model_acc=model_history["accuracy"]
model_valloss=model_history["val_loss"]
model_valaccuracy=model_history["val_accuracy"]

epochs=range(len(model_acc))


plt.plot(epochs,model_valaccuracy,label="Val_accuracy")
plt.plot(epochs,model_acc,label="Accuracy")
plt.show()
```

And that error show up :
`[WinError193]%1 is not a valid Win32 application`

I have a 64bit Windows 10, anaconda 64bit also.

Thanks in advance, I am stuck since two days ago.

Edit 1 : It seems to be a problem with tenserflow.keras library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have a solution. I had the same problem in the past... Then I figured out that there were two python environments involved here. I just had to delete one of them (the one not associated with Anaconda). I hope that this answer will help you.
Good luck with your projet, AI is fun :)

Comment: Thanks !! It worked !!